# Generate doc Blocks for php?

Tags: php, phpdoc

How can i generate **doc blocks** for comments *in* a php file?

Comment: What do you mean by "generate"?

Comment: Gordon, I believe he means that blocks within the PHP files, not system that actually reads them to generate the html based documentation.

Comment: This is a fair question, but it's a dupe of one I think I asked some time ago :) Hang on...

Comment: Hah! Possible duplicate of [A tool to find and fix incomplete source code documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936376/a-tool-to-find-and-fix-incomplete-source-code-documentation) Oh that was the one with the huuuuge answer from @Pascal. Brilliant stuff.

Comment: @Gordon, i wasn't asking you to repost a possible duplicate, i was just saying that i do not think its a duplicate of what you had posted.

Comment: I mean how can I automate it?

Comment: That's the lines I was thinking, +1 @Pekka, and thanks for taking the time to get the post, it was useful to myself :)

Comment: @Aditya Please! You can do better than that. Put up a proper question with actual words describing your situation and the problem and what you want to achieve. Give an example. Dont make us guess.

Comment: @gordon.Sounds good to me. I will keep that in mind .Thanks for taking the time to understand and answer my cryptic question.

Comment: Here is another possible duplicate: [Auto Commenting Tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422793/auto-commenting-tool)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netbeans IDE automatically generates them when you enter "/**" and if you are using Komodo you can use the following macro

http://community.activestate.com/forum/phpdoc-autocompletion

In the end you rely on the IDE you use to support it.