# Automatic creation of doc-blocks for phpdocumentor 2

Tags: php, documentation

while phpdocumentor 2 parses my files, it shows all functions which do not have any DocBlock.
Is there a tool that can create empty (minimal) doc-blocks compatible with phpdoc2 like php-cs-fixer does with code? Then I can go thru the code and fill in all information.

Thanks.

Comment: http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_DocBlockGenerator

Comment: https://github.com/agentile/php-token-docblock-generator

Comment: Quite a few IDEs (Sublime, PhpStorm, etc.) have smart ways of generating doc blocks with stub info on a per function basis, i.e. while you're writing your code: http://www.thenerdary.net/post/42849474901/docblockr-for-sublime-text-2

Comment: Thanks for so many comments in such a short time. I am using PHPStorm, will try the software. Additionaly I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1936421/2466049

Comment: It worked with PHP_DocBlockGenerator, thanks! I installed it before but did not realize there is a bin inside the package (I use pear + php55 on mac with brew)

Comment: If you want to develop such a code generator, please look at GhostDoc. http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx The idea to let customize both in descriptive grammar and actual code files the documentation blocks templates and how to apply them to a precise function is very useful.

I'm using it for 8 years when I code in C# with happiness and would love a similar product for PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the comments on the first post.