# How do I create an automatic code documentation for a PHP project?

Tags: php, cakephp, phpdoc

I have a big project, that uses CakePHP. Now I would like to create a documentation for other new co-workers.

An idea was to use the existing PHPdoc comments and other comments inside the code to create an automatic documentation for a start.

1. How can I manage such a big project and How would I create a browsable HTML-Documentation?
2. How can I **automatically add missing comments**?
   (I use Eclipse for coding, but if it is easier in another editor I wouldn't mind.)
   There are many functions declared like this:

   `# some explanation not in phpDoc`
   `function whatever() {`
   `....`
   `}`

It would be optimal if I could use an external Editor to edit only the phpdoc comments and they were automatically  inserted in the sourcecode at the right positions.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for an _alternative_ to phpDocumentor [phpdoc.org]?

Comment: The **PHP_Beautifier tool** [mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936376/a-tool-to-add-and-complete-php-source-code-documentation?lq=1) sounds like it could do what I want, but that would be a lot of programming itself. I am looking for something that is already finished

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how much this will fulfill your requirement.

But the NetBeans IDE will help you on documentation.

For documentation guide, you can refer the below site:

[Here is a guide for documentation](http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/uses.html)

Please suggest if you can find better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ApiGenerator` plugin. It's a Cake plugin that uses the same syntax as PhpDocumentor, and for generate the document you just have to run a shell command.

https://github.com/cakephp/api_generator

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want automatic comment generation. You really want a easy way to document the code you have.  The problem with automatic documentation is that the program making the documentation can't know more than the source code already documents. It can't infer how to use the code, or suggest why it is organized the way it is.

Your best approach is to name methods and parameters so that they make sense to other users of the code. Plain and simple names are the best. Also make sure to type parameters and return types where ever possible.  It is really helpful to know a method expects a float rather than a string, and returns an int rather than a bool.

Also avoid adding useless comments like

@param int $number

where you specify the type and variable name in the method. This is a completely useless comment.  Add the description of how the parameter is used if you can. If it is obvious, just remove the comment all together.

One of the things about documentation is to know how it will look to the end user. I actually wrote [PHPFUI/InstaDoc](http://phpfui.com/?n=PHPFUI%5CInstaDoc) for this reason, among others. With InstaDoc, you don't have to sit through a rescan of the entire project. InstaDoc uses PHP reflection classes to render the documentation in real time. So if you are working on code, just hit up the local copy of InstaDoc to see how your class will document itself. If you see something is wrong, fix it and refresh the InstaDoc page. BOOM! Your latest changes are now live.

InstaDoc will also generate static pages for high volume sites.  And if you see a problem with InstaDoc, submit an issue or PR and I will be happy to consider it.